# Как правильно сгруппировать записи по названию

Tags: wordpress, cms

Мне необходимо добавить много авторов с одинаковым именем, а потом сгруппировать их по названию. Сгруппировать получается при помощи

```
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'author_groupby');
```

ну и сама функция`author_groupby`

```
function author_groupby()
{
    return 'post_title';
}
```

не мог бы кто подсказать, что и как надо писать в функции, что бы группировка происходила по названию записи, но текст выводился из всех записей. заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В общем сделал все, как мне кажется, намного проще. так как у меня отсутствует пагинация, то я попросту написал скрипт на Jquery, который прячет блоки, которые мне не нужны.